# Bootstrap navbar content positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbxar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation" style="min-width: 320px; height: 51px;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="display: table;">
        <div class="row row-mod">
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7-mod" style="background-color: blue;">
                <a class="navbar-logo pull-left" href="/"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s24.postimg.org/intj0mv3l/logo.jpg" /></a>
                <span class="navbar-footer-text-container">
                    <span class="navbar-footer-text">CUSTOMER SERVICES | <a href="/stores.html" class="store-text">STORE</a> </br>COPYRIGHT © BRND 2006/2014</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5-mod" style="padding-right: auto; background-color: red;">
                <a href="/"><img style="margin-left: 1px;" class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="/"><img style="margin-left: 1px;" class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" /></a>
                <a href="/"><img class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS is added to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/inpos/9uqynLgt/1/).

Currently the problems are:
1. The bigger yellow image is not centered vertically in the blue div, it is on the bottom of the div
2. The smaller yellow images are not centered vertically in the red div, they are on the top of the div
3. The smaller yellow images are not on the right of the red div. There is a little space, I couldn't find why this space appears
4. The yellow images are set to be responsive. I've set this, because I've also set a rule to resize the navbar under 410px to have only 39px height. This feature is necessary, because then on smaller screens the text doesn't have to go to the next row, so everything fits like on bigger screens. The problem is that it isn't working this currently.

Do you have any clues for these problems?

---

Edit:
I would like to achieve the following layout:
1. The bigger image (the logo) and the text should be on the left side
2. The text after the logo must be in 2 lines and the space between the two lines should be small
3. The other three images should be on the right
4. The navigation bar should have a width as the window
5. The content on the navigation bar should have a maximum widht of 976px
6. The navigation bar should have a height of 51px
7. The text should have an 8pt size

These settings should be changed a bit when the screen size is lower than 410px. This is necessary, because under 410px the content cannot fit in the space, so in case the navbar is only 39px and also the images will be resized according to this height than everything can fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main issue is your mix of inline and external styles, quite a mess. Within that mess, you have that bottom nav with a `display:table` declaration. Basically, you're trying to re-invent the wheel. I don't know why are you doing this, but following your logic, I've fixed your code so it works. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otzw3ub1/) and HTML code below.

```
<div class="navbar navbxar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="display: table; padding:0; margin:0 auto">
        <div class="row row-mod">
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-7-mod" style="background-color: blue; ">
                <a class="navbar-logo pull-left" href="/"><img class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-top:-9px; display:inline; vertical-align:50%; height:47px;" src="http://s24.postimg.org/intj0mv3l/logo.jpg" /></a>
                <span class="navbar-footer-text-container">
                    <span class="navbar-footer-text">CUSTOMER SERVICES | <a href="/stores.html" class="store-text">STORE</a> </br>COPYRIGHT © BRND 2006/2014</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-5-mod" style="padding-right: auto; background-color: red; ">
                <img style="margin-left: 1px; margin-top:9px" class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" />
                <img style="margin-left: 1px; margin-top:9px" class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" />
                <img style="margin-left: 1px; margin-top:9px" class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://s4.postimg.org/kus2gqabd/image.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, my suggestion would be for you to use Bootstrap as it is, it really works fine without any reinvention.

Comment: `Container-fluid` exists in BS3 as well: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container but I agree that OP should try to keep it to native bootstrap where possible.

Comment: Ok, I agree that my code is messy, this is because the I try to achieve a layout, but as you see I am not really successful in this. About my layout I am going to edit my question.

Comment: @Dan you're correct, it has been added in newer versions of Bootstrap3, it wasn't in 3.0 and I got used to it, my bad, I'm editing my answer now

Comment: @Fabio can you please help me based on my layout description?

Comment: I already gave you a fiddle with the code for your exact layout, check it out. Anyways, I'm off to sleep, but if you still have issues I can check it out tomorrow or you may find someone else who can help you

Comment: Thanks! I've found a little problem, but I will return with exact description. I hope I can solve with this.